# How to fit and calculate the average for data sets in xmgrace?

Tags: curve-fitting, xmgrace

I have a function which I like to fit it to a function of Y=a+(1-a)exp(-x/T) to get the T value for it.

I want to do these using Xmgrace but I do not know how.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked at the 'how to ask a question' page? You should show us what you have tried, what problem you are having, etc. The link is -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just read it Bas. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the xmgrace window, click  <kbd>Data</kbd>   <kbd>Transformations</kbd> <kbd>Non-linear curve fitting</kbd>.

- On `formula section`, type in 
  `a0+(1-a0)*exp(-x/a1)`
- You have 2 parameters, `a0` and `a1`. On `parametes` section, select 2. Make an inital guess, range, tolerance and number of iterations. Normally default values would suffice for tolerance and iterations.
- Hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>. Keep on hitting it untill a good fit is obtained.

**Note** - A good guess of initial parameters will help you get a good fit faster.